# jsreport - Openlayers not loading

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, report, openlayers, jsreport

I want to have a report (pdf) showing a map with help of Openlayers. Sadly it seems only to work as html and not with chrome-pdf or phanton-pdf.

Here is my code: https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/DLrUNzqm

I already added a fake timeout of 5000 before setting `window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true;`

Anyone got an idea why it is not working?

Comment: Did you try the jsPDF library (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) in connection with canvas.toBlob() (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phantomjs doesn't support the latest javascript so it probably won't work there because of that.

However properly configured chrome-pdf will work. In your case you just need to enable the printing trigger in the recipe properties.

[image]

See the working demo here
https://playground.jsreport.net/w/jan_blaha/PH_1WzLp